# Какой из данных конструкторов более оптимизирован?

Tags: c++, оптимизация, конструктор

Какой из этих двух конструкторов является более оптимальным, быстродействующем?

```
// 1
template <typename T>
Matrix2x2<T>::Matrix2x2(T** m_pp) :
    _v2s({
        m_pp[0],
        m_pp[1]
    })
{}
// 2
template <typename T>
Matrix2x2<T>::Matrix2x2(T** m_pp) :
    _v2s({
        { m_pp[0][0], m_pp[0][1] },
        { m_pp[1][0], m_pp[1][1] }
    })
{}
```

При условии, что `Vector2<T> _v2s[2]`, который имеет конструкторы:

```
template <typename T>
inline
Vector2<T>::Vector2(T* v_p) :
    x(v_p[0]),
    y(v_p[1])
{}

template <typename T>
inline
Vector2<T>::Vector2(T x, T y) :
    x(x),
    y(y)
{}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никакого конкретного ответа на этот вопрос нет и быть не может. Нет  никаких причин полагать, что эти конструкторы как-то отличаются по быстродействию.

Если вы замечаете какую-то разницу - это особенность вашего компилятора. Меряйте ее сами и действуйте соответственно, имея при этом в виду, что завтра без каких-либо видимых причин ситуация может запросто поменяться на прямо противоположную.